# my LM35 temperature sensor gives weird measurements,

Tags: temperature, lm35

Board: esp32

I know my wiring is correct because I get data from the sensor, but the data is a bit weird.

At 22 celcius I get 140, even though if I do the voltage calculation (* 0.473372) it still doesn't work.

the number 0.473372... comes from taking the voltage 4.7v / 1024 * 1000 / 10

My code:

```
 Serial.print("temp: ");
 float temp = (analogRead(A13) * 0.473372781065088);
 Serial.println(temp);
 delay(2000);
```

Any answers?

Comment: What is the voltage into the analog input when you get that reading? Explain why you multiply by 0.473. Show your schematics. I think the LM35 needs decoupling capacitors (if I remember correctly). Have you omitted them? Add the info into your question - not in the comments.

Comment: Your "conversion" from ADC value to temperature looks far too simple.  You have to convert the ADC value to volts, then from the voltage you can calculate the temperature.  This is a simple excercise, and a quick google search turns up examples (with explanations) for using the LM35 with an ESP32.

Comment: What JRE says: remember that 0 = 0 V but 1023 = VCC (unless you chose a different reference voltage).

Comment: qustion is now updated

Comment: @JRE, im not sure what you mean, a short tutorial told me that i should make the conversion: analogRead value * (voltage to the sensor / 1024 * 1000 / 10)

Comment: what do you mean? @Bimpelrekkie

Comment: *analogRead value * (voltage to the sensor / 1024 * 1000 / 10)* I think it should be: Actual Voltage = analogRead_value * (ADC reference voltage / 1023), see: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ReadAnalogVoltage

Comment: [I mean like this.](http://www.esp32learning.com/code/esp32-and-lm35-temperature-sensor.php)

Comment: @JRE thanks, i worked, i guess my voltage conversion was wrong

Comment: how do i close this question?

Comment: You write an answer detailing what was wrong and how you fixed it (for the benefit of people in the future that have the same problem), wait the prescribed period, then accept it as the right answer.

Comment: btw: the esp32 is operated at 3.3V. so, if you really have a voltage of 4.7V at the analog inputs you are out of specs!

Comment: @SimSon what do you mean?

Comment: Normalizing voltage with `4.7v / 1024 * 1000 / 10` makes me believe that you measured/supplied a voltage of 4.7V. That's to much for the esp, the maximum permitted voltage is 3.6V as the esp32 must be operated at 3.3V

Comment: hmm idk, the documentation for the sensor said it needed 4.4 volts, so i just hooked it up with the vin pin

Comment: but i doesnt output 4.4 voltage, so i guess im fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the problem is that i used to the wrong voltage conversion, just use:

```
RawValue = analogRead("your analog input pin");
Voltage = (RawValue / 2048.0) * 3300;
Serial.println(Voltage);
```

this should print the tempeture in celcious

Answer (score -1):

[image]
try this one i have worked with lm35 using this code and circuit. i have done this thing with arduino uno but you can try it with esp32

Comment: i dont need the sensor to measure minus decrease, so i use a diffrent setup